# How can I keep track of sent and received messages in an android messaging app?

Tags: android, sms

I'm new to Android development (but not to Java) and I'm writing my own Android messaging app that hopefully should take the place of the default SMS app. My question is - how does the default SMS app keep track of sent and received messages and how might I accomplish the same task? Specifically, I can't figure out how to find, store, and display a conversation history between the device user and a member of their contact list. I don't have any preliminary code yet, because frankly, I have no idea where to begin.

EDIT: Trying to set up a BroadcastReceiver as a first step (gotta start somewhere) but I'm struggling getting my app to fire when the notification comes through the device  (I'm using emulators).

Here is my BroadcastReceiver Class (based on example from below)

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;


public class smsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "smsBroadcastReceiver";
    private static final String SMS_SENT = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT";
    final SmsManager mySMSManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String phoneNumber, message;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) handleIncMessage(intent.getExtras(), context);
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_SENT)) sendSMS(intent.getExtras(), context);

    }

    void sendSMS(Bundle bundle, Context context){
        phoneNumber = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.e("info", "Outgoing Number: " + phoneNumber);
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("onNewMsgSend"));
    }


    void handleIncMessage(Bundle bundle, Context context) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            //database stuff...
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                String sendingNum = messages[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String message = messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody();

                Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context, conversationView.class);
                msgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.startActivity(msgIntent);

               // Log.i(TAG, "SENDER: " + sendingNum +"; Message: " + message);
                System.out.println("SENDER: " + sendingNum +"; Message: " + message);
            }
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("onNewMsg"));
        }
    }
}
```

My best guess is that I'm doing something wrong in my Activities, but I'm not sure what. Do I need to send my intent to my main (launching) activity and then delegate the intent from there, or can I send it to an activity that isn't the launcher (which is what I'm trying to do now)?

EDIT: BroadcastReceiver problem solved.

Comment: A good start will be contacts permission for your app which you can find here http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html.  You can search their contact list fairly easily so it should be pretty straightforward from there.

Comment: I've established the contacts permission in my manifest file and am reading/displaying the contacts fairly well. My real question is how I keep track of sent and received messages between the user and a member of their contact list and display it in a conversation-style view like the default SMS app does.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**

Step 1.

This is your first home class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Context context;
Activity act;
ListView lvsms;
public static String msg = "msg", phoneNo = "phoneNo", time = "time";

public static String typeMsg = "0";
public static String typeSend = "1";
// String typeDeliver = "2";

TextView smsno_record;

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter1;

BroadcastReceiver onNewMsg = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
};

BroadcastReceiver onNewMsgSend = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
};

// BroadcastReceiver deliveredreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
// @Override
// public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//
// }
// };

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(onNewMsg);
    unregisterReceiver(onNewMsgSend);
    // unregisterReceiver(deliveredreceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    registerReceiver(onNewMsg, new IntentFilter("onNewMsg"));
    registerReceiver(onNewMsgSend, new IntentFilter("onNewMsgSend"));
    // registerReceiver(deliveredreceiver, new IntentFilter(
    // "deliveredreceiver"));
    setContentView(R.layout.complete_sms_data);
    context = MainActivity.this;
    act = MainActivity.this;

    lvsms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvsms);
    smsno_record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsno_record);
    smsdetails(typeMsg);//      sendboxSMS();

}

void smsdetails(String type) {
    Database db = new Database(context);
    // ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = db.getRecord(type);
    LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> al = db.getRecord(type);
    Log.e("test", "sms al :- " + al.size());
    db.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = al.get(i);
        String name = getName(getContentResolver(), hm.get(phoneNo));
        hm.put("name", hm.get(phoneNo) + " " + name);
        Log.e("test", "name :- " + name);
    }
    if (al.size() > 0) {
        lvsms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CustomAdapter adapter = null;

        if (type.equals(typeMsg)) {

            Log.e("test", "if condition 1st");

            adapter = new CustomAdapter((Activity) context, al);
            lvsms.setAdapter(adapter);
            // adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, al,
            // R.layout.list_items_msgs, new String[] { "name", msg,
            // time }, new int[] { R.id.txtPhoneNo,
            // R.id.txtMsg, R.id.txtTime });
        } else if (type.equals(typeSend)) {
            Log.e("test", "if condition 2st");
            adapter = new CustomAdapter((Activity) context, al);
            lvsms.setAdapter(adapter);
            // adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, al,
            // R.layout.list_items_msgs, new String[] { "name", msg,
            // time }, new int[] { R.id.txtPhoneNo,
            // R.id.txtMsg, R.id.txtTime });
        }
        // else if (type.equals(typeDeliver)) {
        // adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, al,
        // R.layout.list_items_msgs, new String[] { "name", msg,
        // time }, new int[] { R.id.txtPhoneNo,
        // R.id.txtMsg, R.id.txtTime });
        // }
        lvsms.setAdapter(adapter);
        smsno_record.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        Log.e("test", "else condition ");
        lvsms.setAdapter(null);
        lvsms.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

}

Step 2.
This is your receiver for sms

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
String phoneNumber, message;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {

        handleIncomingMsg(intent.getExtras(), context);

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT")) {

        sendSMS(intent.getExtras(), context);

    }


}

void handleIncomingMsg(Bundle bundle, Context context) {
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    Database db = new Database(context);
    for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
        String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        String senderNum = phoneNumber;
        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

        Intent in1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        in1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(in1);

        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: "
                + message);
        db.insertRecord(senderNum, message, MainActivity.typeMsg);
    }
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("onNewMsg"));
    db.close();
}

void sysAlert(String title, String msg, Context context) {
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            }).create();
    alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alert.show();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    telephony.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
}

TelephonyManager telephony;

MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener;
boolean ring = false;
boolean callReceived = false;



void handleCalls(Context context) {
    if (phoneListener == null) {
        phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }
}

void sendSMS(Bundle bundle, Context context) {
    phoneNumber = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    Log.e("info", "Outgoing Number: " + phoneNumber);

    Database db = new Database(context);

    db.insertRecord(phoneNumber, "hii", MainActivity.typeSend);
    //
    // }
    db.close();
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("onNewMsgSend"));
}



}
```

Sept 3.
 Put permissions in mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot and let you know how this goes.

Comment: NP, we used receiver for incoming new sms and when new SMS is coming then we can put that new sms any where sqlite or server. You also need to register the receiver

Comment: It seems as though I'm having trouble getting my app to fire when a new message comes through. I'm not sure what's going on, so I posted my receiver code above.

Comment: I resolved my own question. Darn periods being where I don't need them.